# Non Zero Exit Code

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie and have just started coding on CodeChef. The code is showing a NZEC error on their IDE but its working fine in PyCharm

I have submitted it using a Try Except block, but i could not figure out the problem

```
i, j = input().split()

i = int(i)
j = float(j)
if(i % 5 == 0 and i + 0.50 < j):
    r = j - 0.50 - i
    print("%.2f"%r)
else:
    print("%.2f"%j)
```

The output is matching the sample output for all test cases when running on my system with no errors.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check if there is a space between the inputs in the custom input field? if not try a space between the numbers.Because I guess if there is no space between numbers then split method doesn't know what to split.

Comment: A clarifying question should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: I have also answered the question that it could be a space, if you didn't notice